# RoR: Creating a PowerPoint Presentation from a template, in the office365

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, powerpoint, office365api

I need to create a Powerpoint Presentation from a template via smith like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-presentation-document-by-providing-a-file-name?redirectedfrom=MSDN On the Office.com server.

I came across a number of gems, including powerpoint, ruby_slides and etc. but I wasn't able to find any documentation on the Office 365 Api via Ruby.

Am I missing something? could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find only these gem https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ruby-connect-rest-sample.
https://github.com/Plaristote/sharepoint-ruby